# accumulate variables in a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

I have a class with a few member functions that I would like to accumulate and hold value.  This is what is in my main:

```
Class();
    displayLogo();
    char choice;
    Class score;

    cout << "1. Which of these is the coolest?" << endl
         << "a. Bowties" << endl
         << "b. Converse sneakers" << endl
         << "c. Leather jackets" << endl;

    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice){
         case 'a': score.setA(1);
              break;      
         case 'b': score.setB(1);
              break;
         case 'c': score.setC(1);
              break;
              }
```

For each member function I want a number to accumulate every time a specific choice is made and for it to hold the value.  At the end A, B, and C should all have a value from which I would find the highest.

How do I get each member function to accumulate and hold its value?

Comment: Sounds like you just need a member variable for a, b & c to keep score. Your `Class` code would be more usefule than your `main()` code here. Oh, and it's fezzes that are cool http://gph.is/15wg5Qv

Comment: You should start by having code that compiles and just asks the values without accumulating them. Small steps...

Comment: You want to get the number of times each choice is made? if that so why not just have some counters specific for A,B,C in switch cases?

Comment: Then to remember values, you probably want to use *member variables*. Look them up in your C++ book (or Wikipedia or whatever).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Class();` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: thank you for the replies.  fezzes most definitely are cool.  bowties were just more prevalent.

Comment: Class(); is just my constructor.  It just initializes my member variables to zero.  I do have member variables already.  The problem was I was having was having the member variable store the count/sum of each time the choice was being selected.  It would keep reseting back to 0.  At the end I need to determine which was picked the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the requirement needs you to use a class for this, the straight-forward approach is to just store a count for each letter as part of a given instance's state. Simple example:

```
class score_counter
{
  int a, b, c;
public:
  score_counter() : a(), b(), c() {}
  void countA() { ++a; }
  void countB() { ++b; }
  void countC() { ++c; }
  int A() const { return a; }
  int B() const { return b; }
  int C() const { return c; }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I was over-thinking my problem.